# Javascript progress bar doesn't work with Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently setting up a progress bar in my website with Javascript. It works very well with Google Chrome, but not in Firefox... What's the problem ?

```
function uploadFile() {
    var file = document.getElementById("fileToUpload").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("fileToUpload", file);

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "send.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}

function progressHandler(event) {
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    document.getElementById("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "%";

    if (document.getElementById("status").innerHTML == "100%") {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Finalisation...";
    }
}

function completeHandler(event) {
    document.getElementById("progressBar").value = 100;
}
```

I expect the progress bar to work with Firefox, but it does not work at all.

Comment: what does your console log say?

Comment: Nothing, it's totally clear

Comment: I’m facing the same problem ...!!! Console totally clear ! Any clue ?